# How to create Java object in CFSCRIPT?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.1.0

I am trying to create a java object using CFSCRIPT and I just can't get the right combination of stuff to work.

This works perfectly:

```
<cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="CyberSource" name="auth">
<cfset VARIABLES.ResponseString = auth.runTransaction(LOCAL.PropsFile,LOCAL.MyXML)>
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
LOCAL.MyObject = createObject("java", "CyberSource.auth");
LOCAL.ResponseString = auth.runTransaction(LOCAL.PropsFile,LOCAL.MyXML);
```

This is the error I get:

```
Object Instantiation Exception.
Class not found: CyberSource.auth
```

The object is an external piece of code available to ColdFusion. I don't see what the problem is. Do you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classname is CyberSource and the variable you are trying to assign the instance to is "auth" in your tagbased approach. You mixed it up with "MyObject".

```
LOCAL.auth = createObject("java", "CyberSource");
LOCAL.ResponseString = LOCAL.auth.runTransaction(LOCAL.PropsFile,LOCAL.MyXML);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be aware of.

The java class names are case sensitive!

```
// Fail
myFile = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.file' );

// Win!
myFile = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' );
```

And to call their constructor, use `.init()` eg.

```
myFile = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' ).init( '/Users/Mike/Dev/Test' );
```